# Links for sub menus to left hand menu not working

Tags: sharepoint-online, dropdown

A few weeks ago I created a site with a left hand menu and everything is working fine. i am now wanting to add drop down menus to some of the main menus and though I can do this, I am getting error messages when I try to click through and i just can't work out why as the URL appears to be in the same format. I have just been copying the URL from the main heading and then changing the page name. For exmaple, this is the address for my main heading (Catalyst Infrastructure Funding).

[image]

This is the address for my drop down.

[image]

This is my error message.
[image]

I am not very Sharepoint savvy!

Answer (score 0):

Please first make sure the URL with issue is correct and you can access the page without issue. Test it with your browser before you using it in the navigation link.